# ...распрощаться с мечтой состояться

Tags: стилистическая-ошибка

...***но в смутные годы ей пришлось распрощаться с мечтой состояться как известный ученый.*** По-моему, здесь есть какая-то стилистическая ошибка. Если я прав, то в чём именно заключается эта ошибка?

Comment: Главным образом, предложение очень сложно для восприятия из-за перегруженности и неудачного соседства распрощаться-состояться. Если бы было "но в смутные годы ей пришлось распрощаться с мечтой стать актрисой", все бы вполне читабельно было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...**но в смутные годы ей пришлось распрощаться с мечтой состояться как известный ученый.**

Здесь **неправильная сочетаемость** в выражении  "мечта (какая?) состояться".

**СОСТОЯТЬСЯ**, св.  2. Стать кем-л., в полной мере оправдать возлагавшиеся надежды. Как поэт он не состоялся. Как учёный он состоялся.

Он **не состоялся как артист** и всегда это помнил. [Роман Карцев. «Малой, Сухой и Писатель» (2000-2001)]

**Состояться ― это итоговая оценка,** нельзя мечтать от том, чтобы состояться, нельзя сказать: я собираюсь состояться или хочу состояться.

Answer (score 0):

...но в смутные годы ей пришлось распрощаться с мечтой состояться как известный ученый. Может быть, так? Но в смутные годы ей пришлось распрощаться с мечтой стать известным учёным. Или так? Но в смутные годы ей пришлось распрощаться с мечтой состояться в качестве известного учёного. Но фраза действительно синтаксически перегруженная и официально - деловая.